# C# Formatting numbers with spaces delimiting thousands

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I'm trying to format a decimal with the following requirements:

- Thousands are separated by spaces " "
- Decimal point is delimited by a
  comma "," (this is achieved by using the appropriate culture, in this
  case Croatian)
- There are two digits after the decimal point.

So far I got this:

```
String.Format(new CultureInfo("hr-HR"), "{0:# ##0.00}", input)
```

This works well if the number has 4 or more digits before the decimal point. For example the value **5500.5** gives me **"5 500,50"** and **-5500.5** gives me **"-5 500,50"**, which is what I want.

But if the number has fewer digits, I get a white space in front of the number. For example **500.5** gives me **" 500,50"** instead of **"500,50"**. And with a negative number, the space is put between the minus sign and the digits: **-500.5** gives me **"- 500,50"**. So I can't simply trim the result. How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: @HansPassant The negative ruins that method. I had the same thought.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a custom `NumberFormatInfo` to format numbers.

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " "; // set the group separator to a space
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ","; // set decimal separator to comma
```

And then format the number using

```
number.ToString("N2", nfi); // numeric format with 2 decimal digits
```

This gives you

```
(5500.5).ToString("N2", nfi)  // "5 500,50"
(-500.5).ToString("N2", nfi)  // "-500,50"
(-5500.5).ToString("N2", nfi) // "-5 500,50"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach may be to just check if `input` is over a 1000 / less than -1000 before formatting it this way.

```
if(input >= 1000 || input <= -1000){
    // use String.Format(new CultureInfo("hr-HR"), "{0:# ##0.00}", input)
}else{
    // just use input.ToString()?
}
```

There's probably a way to coerce string.format into doing what you want, but why overcomplicate the issue?